# remplazar texto en CSV

Tags: regex

estoy exportando unas tablas `DBF` a `CSV` mediante libreoffice. Este en las cabeceras, me exporta el nombre de la cabecera más caracteres que hacen referencia al tipo de datos y longitud por ejemplo, la columna **NNUMALB**, me la exporta como **NNUMALB,N,7,0** y quiero hacer un remplazo masivo que me elimine todo a partir de la primera coma.
Me podéis echar un cable? Muchas gracias.

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Buenas Emanuel, a lo maximo que he llegado con el ejemplo anterior con `(\w{1,9}),*` y reemplazar por `$1`, pero me envuelve con paréntesis cada uno de los bloques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto, reemplazar expresion regular `,.*` por '' (nada)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ha funcionado

La expresion selecciona todos los caracteres que comienzan por "," y los reemplaza por un caracter vacio. "." denota cualquier caracter y "*" es el cuantificador "todo lo que sigue de aqui en adelante"